# Razer Nabu - integration Issue

Tags: ios, frameworks, linker

I am getting this following error when i try to integrate razer nabu dev SDK framework.

I have did the following .

1. Added the framework - Build Phases
2. set the linker flags to -ObjC
3. set the path for framework - in build settings -> framework search paths

I am wondering still why i am getting this error ..

Any suggestions..

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ReachabilityUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzAuthenticator.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzSocialNetwork.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzMisoSyncer.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzBand.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzMisoUser.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RzMisoLocalCache", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzAuthenticator.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzSocialNetwork.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzMisoSyncer.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzBand.o)
      objc-class-ref in NabuOpenSDK(RzMisoUser.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that framework has further dependencies which should be covered in their documentation (if it's not then raise a bug with them).

The only references to `ReachabilityUtil` I could find are [here](https://github.com/hpbpad/hpbpad-iOS/blob/master/WordPress/Classes/ReachabilityUtils.m).

So the answer is you need to add more frameworks to your project, once you find out what they are.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still have this problem, it can be solved by adding the "Security" framework to your project, and remove the -ObjC flag.

(At least that helped me)

Comment: I didn't need the Security framework myself.

As for the -ObjC flag, I'll second that. Strange how they tell you to add it but it ends up breaking everything... the documentation is sorely lacking :(